delete + insert extremely slow for one particular table
I am using sqlalchemy with a postgresql database hosted on AWS.  I have one particular table that is extremely slow.  Other tables load in seconds.  This particular table can take 10 hours to load ~400 records.  Most of the other tables I use session.bulk_insert_mappings.  It seems like I could not use it on this table because of the Identity column but I could be wrong.  The following is a generic version of what I have and how I am doing the insert.  The table that has the problem is Output.  I also have a local database that does not seem to have the problem.  The database on AWS has to go through a proxy to get there.  Any ideas on how to speed it up?
class MyKey(Base):
    """MyKey table declaration."""
    __tablename__ = 'my_key'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': SCHEMA}
    id = Column(BigInteger, Identity(always=True, start=0, increment=1, minvalue=0, cache=1), primary_key=True)
    year = Column(SmallInteger, nullable=False)
    key1 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    key2 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    key3 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    key4 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    key5 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    level = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    delete_key = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    last_modified_by = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    last_modified_time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    children = relationship('Output', back_populates='parent')
    metric_children = relationship('MetricOutput', back_populates='key_parent')
    metric_detail_children = relationship('MetricDetailOut', back_populates='key_parent')

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"<MyKey(id={self.id}, "
                f"year={self.year}, key1={self.key1}, key2='{self.key2}', key3='{self.key3}', "
                f"key4='{self.key4}', key5='{self.key5}', level='{self.level}', "
                f"delete_key={self.delete_key}, "
                f"last_modified_by='{self.last_modified_by}', last_modified_time={self.last_modified_time})>")

class Output(Base):
    """Output table declaration."""
    __tablename__ = 'output'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': SCHEMA}
    id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(f"{SCHEMA}.my_key.id"), primary_key=False)
    id2 = Column(BigInteger, Identity(always=True, start=0, increment=1, minvalue=0, cache=1), primary_key=True)
    value1 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value2 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value3 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value3 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    value4 = Column(Float, nullable=False)
    value5 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value6 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value7 = Column(SmallInteger, nullable=False)
    value8 = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    value9 = Column(Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    value10 = Column(Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    value11 = Column(Numeric(10, 2), nullable=False)
    value12 = Column(Numeric(7, 2), nullable=False)
    value13 = Column(Numeric(13, 4), nullable=False)
    value14 = Column(Numeric(13, 4), nullable=False)
    value15 = Column(Numeric(13, 4), nullable=False)
    value16 = Column(Numeric(13, 4), nullable=False)
    value17 = Column(Numeric(13, 4), nullable=False)
    value18 = Column(Integer, nullable=False)
    delete = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    last_modified_by = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    last_modified_time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    parent = relationship('MyKey', back_populates='children')
    children = relationship('MetricOutput', back_populates='parent')
    detail_children = relationship('MetricDetailOut', back_populates='parent')

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"<Output(id={self.id}, id2={self.id2}, value1='{self.value1}', "
                f"value2='{self.value2}', value3='{self.value3}', "
                f"value3={self.value3}, value4={self.value4}, value5='{self.value5}', value6='{self.value6}', "
                f"value7={self.value7}, value8='{self.value8}', "
                f"value9={self.value9}, value10={self.value10}, "
                f"value11={self.value11}, value12={self.value12}, "
                f"value13={self.value13}, value14={self.value14}, "
                f"value15={self.value15}, value16={self.value16}, "
                f"value17={self.value17}, value18={self.value18}, "
                f"delete={self.delete}, "
                f"last_modified_by='{self.last_modified_by}', last_modified_time={self.last_modified_time}>")

class MetricOutput(Base):
    """MetricOutput table declaration."""
    __tablename__ = 'metric_output'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': SCHEMA}
    id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(f"{SCHEMA}.my_key.id"), primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(f"{SCHEMA}.output.id2"), primary_key=True)
    metric = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(ARRAY(Numeric(15, 4)), nullable=False)
    delete = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    last_modified_by = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    last_modified_time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    key_parent = relationship('MyKey', back_populates='metric_children')
    parent = relationship('Output', back_populates='children')

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"<MetricOutput(id={self.id}, id2={self.id2}, metric={self.metric}, value={self.value}, "
                f"delete={self.delete_key}, "
                f"last_modified_by='{self.last_modified_by}', last_modified_time={self.last_modified_time}>")

class MetricDetailOut(Base):
    """MetricDetailOut table declaration."""
    __tablename__ = 'metric_detail_out'
    __table_args__ = {'schema': SCHEMA}
    id = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(f"{SCHEMA}.my_key.id"), primary_key=True)
    id2 = Column(BigInteger, ForeignKey(f"{SCHEMA}.output.id2"), primary_key=True)
    detail = Column(BigInteger, primary_key=True)
    metric = Column(Text, primary_key=True)
    value = Column(ARRAY(Numeric(15, 4)), nullable=False)
    delete = Column(Boolean, nullable=False)
    last_modified_by = Column(Text, nullable=False)
    last_modified_time = Column(DateTime(timezone=True), nullable=False)
    key_parent = relationship('MyKey', back_populates='metric_detail_children')
    parent = relationship('Output', back_populates='detail_children')

    def __repr__(self):
        return (f"<MetricDetailOut(id={self.id}, id2={self.id2}, detail={self.detail}, "
                f"metric={self.metric}, value={self.value}, delete={self.delete}, "
                f"last_modified_by='{self.last_modified_by}', last_modified_time={self.last_modified_time}>")

from sqlalchemy import create_negine

db_engine = create_engine(database_uri,
                          pool_size=10,
                          max_overflow=2,
                          pool_recycle=300,
                          pool_use_lifo=True,
                          pool_pre_ping=True,
                          connect_args={'keepalives': 1,
                                        'keepalives_idle': 30,
                                        'keepalives_interval': 10,
                                        'keepalives_count': 5},
                          echo=False)
db_session_maker = sessionmaker(bind=db_engine)
db_session = self.db_session_maker()

table = Output
new_table_list = []
col_list = []
dataframe_columns = dataframe.columns
for col in table.__table__.columns:
    if not isinstance(col.server_default, Identity):
        col_list.append(col.key)
for dfi in dataframe.index:
    new_table = table()
    for col in col_list:
        setattr(new_table, col, dataframe.at[dfi, col])
    new_table_list.append(new_table)
    # db_session.add(new_table)
db_session.add_all(new_table_list)


When I look at pg_stat_activity as suggested I see there is an IO wait_event_type and a wait_event of DataFileRead and the query is
DELETE FROM ss.ss_model_product_out WHERE ss.ss_model_product_out.id = 7
In the real application that is the Output table in what I posted.  I do a delete on the table before I do the insert.  I do not know what the above is telling me it is waiting on.
I am doing a delete by building it up with:
session.query(...).filter(...).delete()
When I look at the query in the debugger it looks fine. The last statement is query.delete() and this is where it hangs for a long time in the debugger.  There are 223 records that will be deleted and 2208 records total in the table.  I cannot figure out why it is taking so long.  I also tried query.delete(synchronize_session=False) and that did not help.
I did a few things that helped a lot:

I increased the size of my AWS RDS virtual machine.  It was hitting its limit.
I added indexes to id in Output and id2 in MetricOutput and MetricDetailOut. I think the delete on Output was making sure id2 was not being used in MetricOutput and MetricDetailOut and it was taking a very long time.  Now the delete is fast but inserting large numbers of records to MetricDetailOut takes a little more time.  I assume it is the overhead of updating the index for id2.



I doubt very much that it has anything to do with the identity column. 2) What does the Postgres log show when inserting into Output?


400 records should be done in a few milliseconds and especially identify columns and their underlying sequence are optimized for performance. There is something else going on, like a locked table. What does pg_stat_activity show you while waiting for your program to finish?

What version of SQLAlchemy are you using?

I am using sqlalchemy version 1.4.46

I added pg_stat_activity to the post

"I do a delete on the table before I do the insert." - So it sounds like you're actually doing an "upsert" from a DataFrame to a PostgreSQL table. In that case, this approach may prove helpful.

If you delete on the id and that id is not indexed (in your example code only id2 is the pk) maybe that is taking longer than you think.  How many rows exist in the output table?  There could be a lot of things going on here.  Also like Gord Thompson said you probably should be using upsert anyways.

added responses in the body.

@webe3 are you able to access the logs?  You might be executing each delete separately, ie. so 223 DELETE statements.  It is hard for us to debug this with so little info.  I would try turning echo=True on the engine and then check the logs.  There will be a lot though so maybe you can export the schema and rebuild the data locally and try to recreate the issue there.

I did a few things that helped a lot.  Updated the post.
